# Why index not cached?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, docker

After running the same query twice I expected data to be cached, but I see data is still read from disk:

```
->  Index Scan using product_pkey on product  (cost=0.42..3.51 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.132..0.132 rows=0 loops=25713)
                           Index Cond: (id = product_property_default.product)
                           Filter: ((lexeme @@ '''laptop'' | ''laptop-ul'''::tsquery) AND ((language)::oid = '20657'::oid))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                           Buffers: shared hit=152936 read=6111
                           I/O Timings: read=2602.604
```

Full plan: https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/oJUn

Query:

```
explain (analyze, buffers)
select distinct "product"."id"
from "product"
    inner join product_property on product_property.product = product.id
where "product"."lexeme" @@ plainto_tsquery('ro'::regconfig, 'laptop')
    and "product_property"."meaning" = 'B'
    and "product_property"."first" in (1.7179869184E10)
    and "product"."language" = 'ro'::regconfig;
```

My index size is 38MB:

```
\di+ product_pkey
                            List of relations
 Schema |     Name     | Type  |  Owner   |  Table  | Size  | Description
--------+--------------+-------+----------+---------+-------+-------------
 pse    | product_pkey | index | postgres | product | 38 MB |
```

Why total buffers count (x8KB) is larger than my index that is only 38MB?

Does it include database fetched rows?

Table size 755MB:

```
\dt+ product
                     List of relations
 Schema |  Name   | Type  |  Owner   |  Size  | Description
--------+---------+-------+----------+--------+-------------
 pse    | product | table | postgres | 755 MB |
```

Config:

- work_mem=64MB
- effective_cache_size=512MB
- shared_buffers=256MB

My database docker container uses low memory. From `docker stats`:

```
NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O
db                  0.32%               75.36MiB / 512MiB   14.72%              359MB / 406MB       64.5GB / 14GB
```

Note that there are other docker services running on the same machine.

`free -h`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.9G        2.9G        143M        274M        850M        488M
Swap:          4.0G        1.7G        2.3G
```

*Using Postgres 12.4 (docker image `postgres:12.4-alpine`)*

Comment: Table and index DDL would be helpful.

Comment: You do realise that Postgres uses the OS filesystem cache extensively?

Comment: @Colin'tHart I see 850M cached but my index is only 38MB. Also the total buffer count seems high. Do the buffers read number include rows read from actual table?

Comment: Though this particual index may be relatively small, your query has to read seven other indexes and a table, which all compete for your puny 256 MB of shared buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index scan is not an index-only scan.  It has to hit the table for every row it finds in the index.  And it looks like "lexeme" is large and has been TOASTed, so it has to read multiple multiple pages to reassemble the full value.  All this disk access is shown in one node, so it is not obvious how much is for the index, and how much is for the table driven from the index.

Do you have a FTS index on lexeme, and it is just not getting used?  Or is the index missing?

Comment: I have a GIN index on `lexeme`, size 151M. Also my lexeme column has weights.

Comment: It might be faster to use the `lexeme` index than to do what it is currently doing, but that is not certain.  If you want to dig into that, you should probably post  a new question focusing on that topic.  You can probably get rid of the joins on offer, stock, and stock_template, as none of them seem to be relevant to the performance issue and just complicate things, but please show the text of the rest of the query.

Comment: updated question with simplified query & plan

Comment: Did a simple test and the `lexeme` index is used when I do a simple query with `@@` without any joins. Don't know why the planner decides not to use it in my original query.

Comment: @cdalxndr How fast was it?  How many rows did it expect to find?  How many did it actually find?  Presumably the planner didn't use it because it thought it would be slower to do so.

Comment: The lexeme idx query, It expected to find 33k rows, but it found 15k rows. The first run was slow (1.7s) due to reading 13k buffers on `bitmap heap scan on product`, the `bitmap index scan on lexeme_idx` needed only 25 buffers. The second run was instant 35ms, hitting cache.

Comment: Unless you are running the identical query (including parameters) over and over in production, I would say the first timing is the relevant one for you.  So it looks like this would not be an improvement over what it is currently doing.  I think you need more RAM, or faster storage hardware.

Comment: For my complex query, it seems that forcing to use the lexeme index (using a subquery) is more efficient, reducing total shared blocks from 90k to 32k, so less data to read from disk.